# Javascript : Do Action after elapsed time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I fire an ajax request AND show a loading sign for the first 6 seconds after the user presses a button :

```
<button onclick="runLoader();"></button>

<script>
    var startTime=(new Date).getTime();
    function runLoader(){
        runAjax();
        var i=0;
        var timer = setInterval(function(e){
            i++;
            //code for loading sign
            if(i==3)
                clearInterval(timer);
        } ,2000);
    }

    function runAjax(){
        $.ajax({
            //
        }).done(function(){
            var timer2 = setInterval(function(){
                var d = new Date();
                var t = d.getTime();
                if(t-startTime>=6000){
                    clearInterval(timer2);
                    // do X
                }
            },500);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to do action **X** only after both `runLoader()` has run for 6 seconds and `runAjax()` has resulted in a response, and no sooner.

Like, if runAjax() responds in 2 seconds, I still want to continue showing loading sign for 6 seconds and then perform **X**. 
And if the loading sign has shown for 6 seconds, I want to wait for runAjax() to return for as long as it takes.

But using the `Date()` method is giving inaccurate results. For eg : It shows 7.765 s elapsed even when only 2 s have passed. I read somewhere I should use `console.log(time)` for better accuracy, but it doesnt work in <=IE9.

Is there a better way to approach this problem ?

**Note:** I am using `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()` because the loading involves cycling through an array of 3 elements, "Fetching", "Processing" and "Loading" each shown for 2 seconds :)

Comment: Why you not use SetTimeout()??

Comment: This is an off-the-cuff response, so please forgive if I just haven't studied your code sufficiently, but could the problem be just a matter of when you're capturing the starttime? That is, you indicate you're getting values too large for your elapsed time, and it appears you're capturing starttime *outside* of any of your functions, meaning it will be too early within the context of your objectives. Sorry if I'm just misunderstanding!

Comment: Have you considered using promises? You could resolve them both independently and then continue once both have finished.

Comment: This would be a LOT simpler with `setTimeout` and a couple of boolean flags, but I'm not clear on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: The 3 states should be correctly handled so that when you say "loading" you actually *are* loading (and not just in some arbitrary point in a time scheme you've invented).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use [`deferred`s](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) and [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
function start(){
    $.when(runLoader(), runAjax()).done(function() {
        //both are now finished
    });
}

function runLoader() {
    //show loader here

    var def = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function() {
        //hide loader here
        def.resolve(true);
    }, 6000);

    return def.promise();
}

function runAjax() {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({...}).done(function(result) {
        //handle response here
        def.resolve(true);
    });

    return def.promise();
}
```

Comment: Really elegant solution. Good stuff.

Comment: A perfect example of deferred - makes it really simple to understand.

Comment: Great answer, but I have a question.  Why return the $.ajax call?  Does that get returned instead of the def.promise()?

Comment: @Javalsu Oops, you're right, that was a mistake. I initially coded it to return the jqxhr object, but changed my mind and forgot to remove that.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  That was confusing me, thanks for the answer, very informative.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a flag to mark it as "ready".  There may be better ways to handle this, but this is just off the top of my head.

```
<script>
    function runLoader(){
        runAjax();
        var i=0;
        var timer = setInterval(function(e){
            i++;
            //code for loading sign
            if(i==3)
                clearInterval(timer);
        } ,2000);
    }

    function runAjax(){
        var timeElapsed = false;
        setTimeout(function(){timeElapsed = true}, 6000);
        $.ajax({
            //
        }).done(function(){
            var timer2 = setInterval(function(){
                if(timeElapsed){
                    clearInterval(timer2);
                    // do X
                }
            },500);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Using setInterval is really confusing the issue.

Comment: I left that in from the original code, I added minimal changes.  But how is it confusing the issue?  It checks the flag every half a second.  If the flag is true then it cancels the interval.

Comment: It's excessive code.  When 1 finishes it checks if they're both done.  If not then the other checks when it finishes.  No need for regular checks at all.

Comment: You don't need a recurring interval, just externalize the check into a function and call it when the loader ends and in the AJAX's `.done()`. It is also a bit friendlier for mobile devices, since executing code demands battery and CPU power, even if just a small amount. See my answer for an example.

Comment: I see your point, but we don't know what "do x" is.  It could require the scope and placing that code in an external function may break the code completely.  Which is why I only addressed the issue of the incorrect timing.

Comment: I am using setInterval() because the loading involves cycling through an array of 3 strings, "Fetching", "Processing" and "Loading" each shown for 2 seconds .. just a little jazz ..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but we're discussing the other setInterval.  They're saying that "do x" should be in a separate function.  And whichever finishes last (either 6 seconds or .done) will call the function and execute "x". And I'm saying that I don't know what "x" is, so I'm not going to move it since I'm not familiar with any of it's dependencies to scope.

Comment: Thoug in nowadays' world I wouldn't recommend adding a minimum load time...
@Javalsu You can then use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to force an context.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pre-caller function that is run on runLoader() and as callback of runAjax(), that will verify if the other action is complete, and then do action X. Example:

```
var ajaxDone = false;
var loaderDone = false;
function doActionX() {
    //your action happens here
}
function tryToDoX() {
    if (ajaxDone && loaderDone) {
        doActionX();
    }
}
function runLoader(){
    loaderDone = false;
    runAjax();
    //show loading sign
    setInterval(function(e){
        //hide loading sign
        clearInterval(timer);
        loaderDone = true;
        tryToDoX();
    }, 6000);
}

function runAjax(){
    ajaxDone = false;
    $.ajax({
        //whatever
    }).done(function(){
        ajaxDone = true;
        tryToDoX();
    }
}
```

It isn't necessary to make a recurring timeout and poll both statuses, because they only get completed once (in every run, i.e. booleans aren't set to false and true while waiting).

**EDIT:** This approach can be used to any asynchronous code that doesn't change status intermitently, even without jQuery.

Comment: Why use `setInterval` and a counter to turn 3 lots of 2 second intervals into 6 seconds???  `setTimeout(function, 6000)`

Comment: I know, I just kept that from the OP's code. this could be simplified greatly. He possibly has some code being executed every 2 seconds, thus the loop.